# SCALA: change the separator in Array

Tags: arrays, string, scala, delimiter

I have an Array like this.

```
scala> var x=Array("a","x,y","b")
x: Array[String] = Array(a, x,y, b)
```

How do I change the separator `comma` in array to a `:`. And finally convert it to string like this.

```
String = "a:x,y:b"
```

My aim is to change the comma(separators only) to other separator(say,`:`), so that i can ignore the comma inside second element i.e, `x,y`. and later split the string using `:` as a delimiter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I'll take a shot.

To go from:

```
val x = Array("a","x,y","b")
```

to

```
"a:x,y:b"
```

You can use `mkString`:

```
x.mkString(":")
```